# Problem with update-database on Visual Studio 2022 ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, database-migration, visual-studio-2022

I am getting this error and I really don't know what to do:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.)

I am using VS 2022 with .NET 6.0 version for my ASP.NET Core MVC web application project.

Whenever I am using `update-database` after `add-migration` I am getting this error.

[image: error]

Answer (score -1):

Please check your configuration for db connection. It seems a db is configured where youd dont have access or a database which is remote but does not exist.

Mostly you find the connection in local.settings file.

Comment: Hey how do I do that?

Comment: Look in appsettings or local.appsettings (expand the files) files or webconfig